# Python Beautiful Soup WebScraping: Return only new data?

Tags: python, database, beautifulsoup

I am new to the world of webscraping in Python but my ultimate skill I want to develop is to store scraped data into a database and have that data refreshed periodically.

My question is: How would you save on data requests (time, bandwith usage), to only request the data that is new since you last ran a script?

For example, my code returns the listings of cars on the website Autotrader:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#URL and headers so it thinks we are a browser
url = "https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?search-target=usedcars&is-quick-search=true&radius=&onesearchad=used&onesearchad=nearlynew&onesearchad=new&make=AC&model=&price-from=&price-to=&postcode=sw65bg"
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

#Request
request = requests.get(url, headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

#Find the name box
name_box = soup.find_all('h2', attrs={'class' : 'listing-title'})

#Print the name_box results to see them
for listing in range(len(name_box)):
    temp = name_box[listing]
    value = temp.text
    print(value)
```

Instead of using a database, I can store the output in a dataframe to help illustrate my question:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])

#Print the name_box results to see them
for listing in range(len(name_box)):
    temp = name_box[listing]
    value = temp.text
    data = data.append({'A' : value}, ignore_index=True)
```

Which outputs:

```
    A
0   AC Cobra 6.3 2dr
1   AC Cobra 4.9 MK IV 2dr
2   AC Cobra 3.5 2dr
3   AC Cobra 3.5 2dr
4   AC Cobra 5.3 2dr
5   AC Cobra 5.7
6   AC Cobra 4736 Built By Gardner Douglas 4.7 2dr
7   AC Cobra 5.7
8   AC Cobra 5.7 2dr
9   AC Cobra 5.8
```

If a 10th AC Cobra appeared on the website, is there a way to just either show, or append that new entry so that I could identify new ones as they appeared?

Answer (score 1):

If the page sends an [`ETag` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) (basically a checksum of the page), you can database that and send it with your next request. If there's no change, the server will send back a `304` (no change), and you can stop.

If the page sends a [`Last-Modified` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified), you can database it and compare it with the `Last-Modified` header in the next request. To save processing, check the head before scraping. If the page rarely changes, you can save bandwidth by [downloading only the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754478/sending-a-http-request-that-tells-server-to-return-only-headers-and-no-body).

Or, even better, send a request with an [`If-Modified-Since` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since), and the server should return a `304` or `200` (full response) depending on whether the page is newer than your last timestamp.

Of course, **all this depends on the server/page owner being nice** by sending and handling helpful headers. Unfortunately, I don't see an `ETag` or `Last-Modified` header coming with your example page.

Ultimately, the only way to be certain there's no new data is to scrape it and compare it to what's in your DB. You can optimize that process as much as possible by writing slick scraping and DB code.