# How can I ignore the request body in Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an application that is using `axios` for request. I have an API I would like to hit, which redirects me to another URL. In the redirect URL, there is a very large request body (multiple MBs) that I do not care about.

I know I can get the redirect URL using `response.request.res.responseUrl` ([source](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/390)).

Is there a way to make this request, get the redirect URL, but cancel the request so I don't incur the cost of loading the request?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754478/sending-a-http-request-that-tells-server-to-return-only-headers-and-no-body

see https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1324

Comment: HTTP has support for a HEAD request, that gives only the headers for a particular request. Usually in redirects, the redirect URL comes in the `Location` header field. Axios has support for this kind of request via the `axios.head(url [, config])` function.

Comment: @eltonkamami yup! That will do it, thank you! If you want to make it an answer I'll be glad to accept it.